# Gluing Post Base To Concrete

Tags: concrete, structural, adhesive

I recently found out that one of the posts which support my roof is free to move around. The post bracket had rusted out and came out. Is there any way I can glue a post bracket to the concrete using concrete epoxy, then shim the post up back to the original height? The post is 5.5” x 5.5” x ~16’ tall.

[image: basic post bracket]

[image: my post]

[image: top of post]

Comment: What is the connection of the post at the top? (A pic would help.) I'm wondering if you can remove the post temporarily.

Comment: Was the post free standing on the concrete before? If so, you can jack the post up and insert step stone below, or pour a new concrete pad/pedestal to level/support the post.

Comment: Notice how the bottom of the post is rotting - moisture is getting stuck underneath it.

Comment: I’ve added a picture of the top of the post. It’s not the exact one that needs work (it’s dark and can’t get a picture now) but the concept is the same.

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following:

1. support the roof - and jack it up a 1/2” extra to enable the new one to slide in.
2. drill and cement or epoxy the post support ( stainless is good) into place, these are usually adjustable so getting the roof level is possible.
3. measure the required length of post - from the support to the roof and the 1/2” can be accounted for in the adjustment.
4. fit the post - the bottom support may be a “cup” which might need one side reducing or it may only be a U, which means the post end can slide in easily.
5. adjust the post height while removing the jacking supports.

May be worth treating the post ends and painting before fitting though.

Answer (score -1):

You have 3 main issues: 1) Hold your post and roof up, 2) Hold your post and roof down, and 3) Maintain a minimum of 6” distance from the post to the ground.

1. You need a steel connector with a mechanical anchor (bolt, etc.) to support and hold the post in position. There are several types of connectors that are suitable for retrofit applications...see below.
2. Likewise, a steel connector with a mechanical anchor will “hold” the post and roof down (providing the top of the post is anchored to the roof properly.)
3. The bottom of the post needs to be cut off so it’s elevated a minimum of 6” above grade.

Because the post is about 16’ long, I’d suspect that the roof could be temporarily supported so the post could swing out of the way a few inches so the anchor could be installed. I’d use something like the Simpson ABU 66Z

https://www.strongtie.com/resources/product-installers-guide/abu-installation

Get the correct type of galvanizing for your area.

Comment: Is the 6” above grade applicable everywhere?

Comment: Also, when you say above grade, is that above the cement, or the dirt?

Comment: It’s 6” above dirt everywhere, unless you have special pressure treatment on the wood...which you don’t because the post is not incised. However, there are no post “cops” out there measuring the exact distance. I suspect you live in a fairly dry area, because the bottom of the post isn’t completely dryrotted away. So, keep the post off the concrete and you should be fine.